# How to see process with arguments in windows using any cygwin utilities

Tags: windows, process, cygwin, arguments, ps

If I use `ps -efW`, it is listing the Windows processes, but not with command-line arguments.

I came across three links where I was told to use `pstree`, `/proc/PID/cmdline`, and `procps`.

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2007-04/msg00813.html

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2007-04/msg00817.html

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2007-04/msg00821.html

However, I dont find any except `procps` in Cygwin 32-bit packages.

Even after I installed `procps`, I don't know how to use it.  I read the man page, but didn't get a clue.

Can someone please help?

For example, using the `wmic` command, I can see the complete process with arguments.

```
C:\Users\test1>wmic process get ProcessID, Commandline /format:csv |grep cmd
OSWIN7VC10-32B1,"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" ,2904
OSWIN7VC10-32B1,C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\ostore74\src\osci\scripts\buil
d_test\nt\batch_conf\winnt_vc100_weekly.bat &gt;C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Tem
p\s1io.4 2&gt;C:\Users\test1\AppData\Local\Temp\s1io.5,3968
OSWIN7VC10-32B1,C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin\ant.bat -
Djboss.home=C:\ostore74\tmp\javaee\jboss-4.2.3.GA -emacs -k -f C:\ostore74\src\j
mtl\build.xml overnight &gt;&gt; \\ostorenas\odi\ostore_platform_logs\ostore\7.4
.0\test1\winnt_vc100\2013-10-18-1720\unit_retail_jmtl.log 2&gt;&amp;1,1864
OSWIN7VC10-32B1,"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" ,604
OSWIN7VC10-32B1,grep  cmd,2064
```

However, using the Cygwin `ps` command.

```
C:\Users\test1>ps -efW |grep cmd
       0    2904       0 ?          Oct 17 C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
       0    3968       0 ?          Oct 18 C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
       0    1864       0 ?          Oct 18 C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
       0    3200       0 ?        08:39:43 C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 14):

If you need arguments only for cygwin processes, you can use

```
procps -wwFAH
```

or

```
pstree -a
```

(`pstree` is a part of the psmisc package).

If you need arguments for Windows processes, you can use `wmic` as well.  It works in the Cygwin shell.  Alternatively, you can try to patch `process.c` of the [win7util package](http://kevinboone.net/README_win7util.html) to include a full command-line.

Answer (score 3):

"pgrep -a" will also do the trick.  For example:

```
$ emacs-w32.exe somefile.txt &

$ pgrep -a emacs
21564 emacs-w32 somefile.txt

$ pgrep -a .   #to see all processes
```

Answer (score 2):

Preface:  Ok... So this was a really annoying one. There just didn't seem to be any viable way to programmatically grab this information into Cygwin. Anytime I started on a solution, it took more than 20min, dismissing the path/solution and back-burner it. Using WMI, Wmic, even pulling from registry, became ridiculous. Nothing provided dependable out, and most of the time even WMI didn't list the CMD line. Always ended up building out a dll/exe analyzer.

Then today I was doing some DLL work, irrespective of Cygwin, and typed "listdlls". At first I thought it was just some rolled function or alias, most likely Nirsoft's [RegDLLView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html). But quickly realized its probably Sysinternal's [listdlls.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656), which is command line!

Solution:

- look-up and store pid for executable name search term
- store results of "listdlls.exe"
- loop through array of pids \
- lookup pid process name \
- print the matching command line for process name against listdlls results

For rough example (dependencies = listdlls.exe, grep, awk, ps "procps"):

```
__getexecmd () {
    [ -z "$@" ] && return 1
    local term="$@"
    hash listdlls || return 1
    local dlls="$(listdlls)"
    for i in $(ps -Wa | awk '/'"$term"'/ {print $1}'); do
        echo "$dlls" | grep -A1 "$i" | awk '/Command\ line\:/{gsub(/Command\ line\:\ /,"");print $0}'
    done
    return 0
}
```

I really think this is what you were after.
Let me know. Cheers

Comment: What is this "__getexeccmd" function?  That isn't a bash function. How is someone supposed to use this?

Comment: Use it however you wish... You could load it into your bash profile, maybe a friendlier name.... You could easily transform it into a bash script, throw it in "usr/bin" or alias it.